# Any plugin doesn't works / wordpress

Tags: wordpress

**Hi everyone,**

first sorry for my english I´m not a native speaker.

I work for my friend on web based on wordpress. It´s simple small web with four sub-pages. He had web there before, but he don´t carre about him. He had there some malware so I decided delete all ( including databases ) and do new instalation. I instaled theme **Alhena-lite** - its free theme.

I added my own css, and on contact page I added google javascipt map api. Then I downloaded plugin ( contact form 7 ), activated and then if I´m wanted customize site I see only blank page - without error alert.  All others functions work correctly except this. And plugin doesn´t work correct too.

OK, I said, probably theme and plugin are incompatible, so I deleted contact form and I download and activated NINJA FORMS - situation was same as was before.

Ok, I tried other plugin and situation was same. If a deactivate this plugins everything was correct ( I  had active only one plugin in same time ).

I tried reinstal the newest version WP, but problem persisted. I tried change permissions - nothing are happen. I tried also activated basic WP theme twenty seventeen and issue persist. The problem with the free space on hosting is certainly not.

I found in the console this:

**Could not load the source for http://www.vlasak-kominy.cz/wp-admin/customize.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vlasak-kominy.cz%2F.
[Exception… “Component returned failure code: 0x80470002 (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED) [nsIInputStream.available]” nsresult: “0x80470002 (NS_BASE_STREAM_CLOSED)” location: “JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js :: onResponse :: line 464” data: no]
Stack: onResponse@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js:464:23
onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:131:17
Line: 464, column: 0**

But I don´t know how solve it and I tried find answer everywhere.

I also found that my hosting use PHP 5.3 ( I sent a request to upgrade on 5.6version because 7 is not available there ). Can be reason issue this ? I cannot activate any plugin.

I believe that you understand my english and thanks in advance.

Richard

Comment: In wp-config.php - add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` Then activate Ninja Forms or Contact Form 7. This will give you errors and not just a blank screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for you answer - yesterday evening my hosting upgraded me php version from 5.3 to 5.6 and seems to everything work correct.  WP recommend at least 5.6 version so probably it was cause my problems.